# Missing files on branch after cvs2svn import

Tags: branch, cvs2svn

A colleague has imported a CVS repository into a pre-existing SVN repository using a cvs2svn dumpfile (like "svnadmin load --parent-dir /path < dumpfile") , which I originally created from the CVS repo.

Now that I'm trying to checkout and build from SVN, I've noticed that some files seem to be missing in the SVN checkout that were present when I checked out the same branch from CVS, although the majority are present. They are mostly but *not* exclusively binary files (jars and gifs etc.) and I *think* (though I haven't checked exhaustively) that they are also files that have not been modified on the branch that I'm trying to check out. I should also point out that they don't show up using cvsweb (I would provide a link to the cvsweb documentation but I have no way of knowing its version etc), although they do appear doing a standard checkout of the branch.

If anyone has any idea what's wrong here, or where to start looking to address this, I'd be very grateful! New to SVN so not sure if this is normal! Also, I know I could fairly easily "fix" it by copying over the files but I'd ideally like to keep their revision history so a more complete solution would be preferable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds that the configuration which has been used during the conversion has been wrong. May be a property in svn exists which represent the CVS revision information. If not you're lost..more or less...A good suggestion is to test such migrations and check the contents of the resulting SVN repository...and of course do make backups ...BTW. Are these branches are removed in CVS before?

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal; such files should be handled just fine by cvs2svn.  Your best bet is to create a reproducible test case (instructions for doing so are in [the cvs2svn FAQ](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#reportingbugs)) and report the problem to the cvs2svn users' mailing list.